# How to capture content of following markdown comments using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently use `/^<!--\n((.|\n)*)\n-->/` but all lines between first `<!--` and last `-->` are captured.

```
<!--
Title: Foo
-->

# This is a test

<!--
Title: Bar
-->
```

Comment: Check about greedy vs non-greedy modifiers.

Comment: @Al.G.: Quantifiers.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte will look it up thanks! In the meantime, do you mind suggesting an answer? Spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Comment: @sunknudsen: instead of `(.|\n)*?` that is perfectly correct but not very performant with regex engines like the Javascript one, use `[\s\S]*?` (a character class with all white-space characters `\s` and all characters that aren't white-spaces `\S`, in other words: all characters including newline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the lazy `?` quantifier, as the comments pointed out.  That's all.

```js
const regex = /^<!--\n((.|\n)*?)\n-->/gm;
const string = `<!--
Title: Foo
-->

# This is a test

<!--
Title: Bar
-->`;
const matches = string.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Thanks! Amazing how powerful one character can be!

Answer (score 0):

You use a greedy quantifier (quantifiers are by default greedy) instead of a lazy/non-greedy/reluctant quantifier. Many posts are related to this problem but this isn't the only problem of your pattern.

You use `(.|\n)*` to spread over multiple lines: that is correct but not efficient for backtracking regex engines (you can use that with `grep` or `sed` but this is better to avoid it with Javascript/PHP/Python/Ruby...).
A way consists of using `[\s\S]*`, but in your particular case you can also use a more descriptive subpattern, since the starting tag is followed by a newline and the closing tag is preceded with a newline.

To reduce the number of tests needed by something like `\n[\s\s]*?\n-->` (that tests for each character taken by `[\s\S]*?` if `\n-->` follows), you can replace `[\s\S]*?` with `.*(?:\n.*)*?`. This time, `\n-->` is only tested once per line instead of once per character.

The pattern becomes `/^<!--\n(.*(?:\n.*)*?)\n-->/gm`.

But there's always a problem: What about empty comments since there's 2 mandatory newlines in this pattern? *(an empty comment has only one newline.)*

You can use: `^<!--\n(.*(?:\n.*)*?)\n?^-->/gm` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/quyOWu/1)

This pattern makes the last `\n` optional to allow to capture the empty string with a simple alternation. On the other hand, to ensure that this one is present when the comment isn't empty, I added the anchor `^`.